# ServletRequest.getParameterValues returns only first value

Tags: java, jsp

I am assigning an integer converted into string value to a hidden input through a  loop where s1 is the loop iterator.

```
<% int k=0; 
String s1 = null;
while(mar.next()){ 
k++;
s1 = Integer.toString(k);%>
<table>
<tr><td><b>User Name </b> </td> <td><%= mar.getString("UserName")  %></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Type </b></td><td> <%= mar.getString("Type")  %></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Complain </b></td> <td><%= mar.getString("Complaint")  %></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Status </b> </td> <td><%= mar.getString("Status")  %></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Date </b> </td> <td><%= mar.getString("Date") %></td></tr>
</table> 
<form action = "demo1.jsp" method = "post">
<% out.println(mar.getString("Id")); %>
<input type="radio"  name = "<%= mar.getString("Id") %>"value="pending"checked>Pending
<input type="radio"  name = "<%= mar.getString("Id") %>" value="done">Done
<input type="submit" name = "B" id = "submit" >
<input type = "hidden" name = "try" value = <%= s1 %> >
<% out.println(s1); %>
</form>

<br>
<br>
<%
 }
```

Below is the code which should return a string of values from 1 to 3 (values of s1)

```
String[] vals;
vals = new String[3];
out.println(vals.length);
vals = request.getParameterValues("try");

out.println(vals.length);

for(int i=0; i<vals.length; i++){
    out.println("Hy");
    out.println(vals[i]);
}
```

It is only returning one value which is the first one and printing vals.length prints 1.

Comment: Can you share full JSP loop code?

Comment: I edited the code in the original question.

Comment: Where/how do you pass in more than one value for `try`? You have three separate forms as written.

Comment: There is only one hidden input per one form. An each time I think your first form is getting submitted. So you are getting first value in java code

Comment: Then how do I submit rest of the forms. Any help?

Comment: Through javascript/ Jquery. There are lots of answers to submit form from jquery. Just search it

Comment: You shouldn't be creating three forms at *all* if you want to submit a single form with multiple values. *Why* are you creating three forms? On purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating three forms. For each form there will be separate request made. Since each form contains only one hidden input you will always get only one value for each request for below code

```
 request.getParameterValues("try");
```

Now if you have to submit all the forms with one click. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563299/submit-multiple-forms-with-one-submit-button) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805108/submit-multiple-forms-with-same-name-with-one-click-jquery) are the answers